# Why are loop-induced processes finite without counter terms?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, regularization

When a process has no tree-level contribution to the amplitude but occurs e.g. at 1-loop level it is said to be loop-induced. One property of loop induced processes is when you calculate the amplitude there are no counter terms from renormalization. Therefore the amplitude is "inherently finite", why?

Comment: The amplitude must be UV finite indeed, but may still contain singular terms originating from the IR.

Comment: To renormalize you introduce counterterms diagrams of lower loop order. If there are no tree diagrams to begin with, you cannot renormalize a one-loop quantity. Therefore it has to be UV finite, otherwise it would be unphysical

Comment: @Hausdorff your comment needs to be promoted to an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When renormalizing you introduce counterterm diagrams of lower loop order, constructed from counterterm interactions. Importantly, during renormalization you do not introduce any interactions that were not in the Lagrangian in the first place.

So, if there are no tree diagrams to begin with, you also do not have any counterterm diagrams that would contribute at the same order as one-loop diagrams, and you have no way of cancelling potential UV divergences. Your process therefore has to be free of these divergences, since otherwise it would be unphysical.